# Interpolation CSV file with multiple columns

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have a CSV file containing data in the following form:

```
[(    7, 1818,  1,  8, 1818.021, 65, 10.2,  1, 1)
 (   12, 1818,  1, 13, 1818.034, 37,  7.7,  1, 1)
 (   16, 1818,  1, 17, 1818.045, 77, 11.1,  1, 1) ...
 (73715, 2019, 10, 29, 2019.826,  0,  0. , 30, 0)
 (73716, 2019, 10, 30, 2019.829,  0,  0. , 24, 0)
 (73717, 2019, 10, 31, 2019.832,  0,  0. , 28, 0)]
```

each column corresponding to different data. The 2nd column corresponds to the year. I have to interpolate all the data in 1000 time steps from 1900 to 2000.
The difficulty lies in the fact that it's a CSV file with multiple columns which I have to interpolate each in 1000 time steps.

What I first did is collect all the data from 1900 to 2000 with this piece of code:

```
index1 = np.where(arr['year']==1900)[0][0]
index2 = np.where(arr['year']==2000)[0][-1]
data = arr[index1:index2]
```

which gives:

```
[(29950, 1900,  1,  1, 1900.001,  12,  3. ,  1, 1)
 (29951, 1900,  1,  2, 1900.004,  12,  3. ,  1, 1)
 (29952, 1900,  1,  3, 1900.007,   3,  2. ,  1, 1) ...
 (66836, 2000, 12, 28, 2000.99 , 162,  7. , 13, 1)
 (66837, 2000, 12, 29, 2000.993, 151, 11.7, 15, 1)
 (66838, 2000, 12, 30, 2000.996, 152, 10.6, 11, 1)]
```

The length of this piece of data is 36889. Now I need to interpolate this in 1000 time steps.

I've got no idea how to do this. I've been going back and forth with np.interpd() and interp1d from scipy, but I keep getting stuck since there are no clear examples as to how to do this with each column from a csv file.

I want this done without pandas and without for loops.

Comment: You can convert your NumPy dataset/array from  numpy.genfromtex to Pandas DataFrame and then let the pandas do the interpolation work. Most likely the best is to use some Datetime index based on your data, so that pandas would think that this is some data in timespace, but if your data is sorted, then it would not matter. 
I do not quite understand what is "Now I need to interpolate this in 1000 time steps". Does it mean you have to reduce your data to only 1000 points instead of 36889 points?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can interpolate using some integer index values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# let us generate the sample data, similar to data in question:
dvec = [datetime.datetime(1818,1,1)+ii*datetime.timedelta(days=1) for ii in range(200*365)]
# --------------------------------------------------------------
yy = [vv.year for vv in dvec]
mm = [vv.month for vv in dvec]
dd = [vv.day for vv in dvec]
c1 = np.random.random(np.size(yy))
c2 = np.random.random(np.size(yy))
c3 = np.random.random(np.size(yy))
datain = np.vstack((yy,mm,dd,c1,c2,c3)).T
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# let us convert our data to pandas dataframe:
ddict = {ii:datain[:,ii] for ii in range(datain.shape[1])}
# we can also add just some index values for the interpolation:
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# let us interpolate to wished values using integer values:
kk = [kk for kk,val in enumerate(dvec,1) if val.year>=1900 and val.year<2000]
iout = np.linspace(kk[0],kk[-1],1000)
ddict['index'] = np.linspace(1,datain.shape[0],datain.shape[0])
# ------------------------------------------------------------
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ddict);
dfi = df.set_index('index');
dfo = dfi.reindex(dfi.index|iout) # add new index values to the dataframe
dfo = dfo.interpolate(method='linear').loc[iout]
```